# How to enforce custom file tree hierarchy in C++ Qt Project using Qt Creator IDE

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a C++ Qt project in which the *.pro file is located one level above individual subfolders containing source (*.cpp), header (*.h) and form files (*.ui), respectively. In other words, the folder which contains the *.pro file within the file system looks something like the following:

```
project.pro
headers\
forms\
src\
```

Suppose the headers and forms folders separately contain form.h and form.ui, respectively, while the src folder contains form.cpp and main.cpp. The relevant portion of my *.pro file looks something like the following:

```
SOURCES += src/main.cpp \
           src/form.cpp

HEADERS += headers/form.h

FORMS += forms/form.ui
```

When Qt Creator displays this on the project-view sidebar, it organizes the files above as follows:

[image]

I simply want the project sidebar to reflect the file organization as it is on the file system, or at least I would like to eliminate this redundant organization as shown. Is there a way to achieve this? I know that there is "File System" view that I can select from the drop-down menu just above the Projects sidebar. This still does not achieve what I want, especially since I use qmake to generate a project for the Xcode IDE (in which it replicates similar behavior in the Xcode project as shown in the picture above).